# How to beautify code in PhpStorm and other Intellij editors?

Tags: phpstorm

Is there any way to beautify my php code in PhpStorm? (a keyboard shortcut would be preferable)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Select code to reformat and press <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + Shift + L</kbd>

This is tested and working (**Ubuntu**), cheers!

**For Mac:**

> Select code to reformat and press <kbd>Command + Alt + Shift + L</kbd>
>
> For full page code reformat <kbd>Alt + Command + L</kbd>

Tested in phpStorm 2018.1.1

Comment: On **some Linux environments** this shortcut may be assigned to system commands (i.e., Lock screen). You can simply change it in `Settings - Keymap` - search for `"Reformat code"`

Answer (score 85):

Choose `Code | Reformat Code`, or press <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd>.

EDIT: The keyboard shortcode has changed since PHPStorm 10 for windows to <kbd>**Ctrl + Alt + F**</kbd>

Comment: On OSX, it's Alt+Cmd+L (version 2016.2.1)

Comment: additionally You can hit `Alt + Cmd + Shift + L` for ability to choose scope (only selected content, whole file etc.) of reformatting (prettifying) the file - on OSX, PhpStorm version 2018.1

Comment: **Tune codestyle** via `Settings - Editor - Code Style`. Then **standardize codestyle with teammates** via `Export` or (better) `Copy to project` (near `Scheme` drop-down list) if project directory is attached to any Version Control System. Bad (but identical for entire team) codestyle is better then no codestyle :)

Comment: This shortcut will reformat selected text only or **entire file** (if no text selected). For me, it is better to use this periodically without any selection to keep entire file standardized.

Answer (score 4):

Under the 'Code' menu there is an option to Reformat Code. In the project settings there is an option to set code style for each file type.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes Code | Reformat isn't enough.

As an example, after reformating a very ugly code I got this result

```
 public function createAction(Request $request)

{

    $news = new News();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


    $form = $this->get('form.factory')
        ->createNamed(

            'backend_news',

            'backend_news',

            $news,

            array(

                'action' => '',

                'method' => 'POST',

                'attr' => array(

                    'class' => 'form-horizontal',

                    'role' => 'form'

                )

            )

        )->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Valider'));;


    $form->handleRequest($request);


   [...]

    return $this->render('BackendNewsBundle:List:form.html.twig', array(

        'form' => $form->createView()

    ));

}
```

In this case you need to go to

> Preferences | Editor | Code Style | PHP

and from here fine tune. Then reformat again.
Example for this file it was a lot of blank line, so I put to 0 the 'In Code' section of the Blank Lines tab. Once I reformated the code I put it back to 2. Anyway a lot of tuning is possible in this section.

Comment: why downvote ? My answer add extra informations showing a real exemple

Comment: maybe it will be better to edit/comment top answer to show your advise to more people?

Answer (score 2):

This has since been changed in PHPStorm 10 to `Code | Format Code` <kbd>**Ctrl|Cmd + Alt + F**</kbd>

Comment: On OSX, it's Alt+Cmd+L (version 2016.2.1)