# How to display a file in PhpStorm not minified?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, hotkeys

Opened a file in PhpStorm and got the following:

[image]

How to display a file in PhpStorm not minified? Tried to google - [Google](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB+%D0%B2+phpstorm+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%B2+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5&newwindow=1&sxsrf=AB5stBg2wbJNKf3rfiLWQLcC5-DWDXR3Ww%3A1689785979574&ei=exa4ZPy7Ipb-qwHV8YG4BA&oq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB+%D0%B2+phpstorm+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%B2+%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiYtC60LDQuiDQvtGC0L7QsdGA0LDQt9C40YLRjCDRhNCw0LnQuyDQsiBwaHBzdG9ybSDQvdC1INCyINC80LjQvdC40YTQuNGG0LjRgNC-0LLQsNC90L3QvtC8INCy0LjQtNC1KgIIADIHECMYsAIYJ0j8UVCyPVjgRnADeAGQAQCYAaEBoAGZA6oBAzAuM7gBAcgBAPgBAcICChAAGEcY1gQYsAPCAgYQIRgKGCriAwQYACBBiAYBkAYI&sclient=gws-wiz-serp), but didn't find anything suitable.

I want someone to help me find the information I need.

Comment: Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937101/how-to-beautify-code-in-phpstorm-and-other-intellij-editors